# Dimensionality of proper subspaces of uncountable dimensional vector space.

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, vector-spaces, ordinals

Given $W$ a vector space and $V$ a proper subspace of $W$, which has a basis set with cardinality uncountable infinity.

> Can the function $F:\mathcal W \to \mathcal V$, ever be bijective, for some pair of $(\mathcal W, \mathcal V)$? $$$$Where
> $\mathcal W, \mathcal V$ denotes an arbitrary basis of space $W$ and $V$ respectively?

If instead of uncountable basis set we have atmost countable basis then the answer is a clearly NO.

But how to argue rigorously for uncountable case?

> How to characterise the set of proper subspaces $V$ such that such a bijection $F$ exists, for each $W$?

Thanks.

Comment: If $V,W$ have the same cardinality, there is no issue to find a bijection between those. Why do you think it is impossible in the countable case?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net I said $V$ is **proper** subspace of $W$.

Comment: $\mathbb R \times \{0\}$ is a proper subspace of $\mathbb R^2$ and as they have the same cardinality, you can find a bijection between those.

Comment: I am asking for bijection of basis $\mathbb R \times \{0\}$ has dimension 1 i.e basis set cardinality 1 whereas $\mathbb R^2$ has dimension 2 i.e basis set cardinality 2. how can there be a bijection?

Comment: You're not asking for a bijection then. **But for a bijective linear map**. You should update the question then.

Comment: I asked for a bijection between the basis sets of V and W.

Comment: This is not what you wrote!
>Can the function $F:\mathcal W \to \mathcal V$, ever be bijective, for some pair of $(\mathcal W, \mathcal V)$? Where 
$\mathcal W, \mathcal V$ denotes an arbitrary basis of space $W$ and $V$ respectively?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133613/discussion-between-bijayan-ray-and-mathcounterexamples-net).